# JDBC: How to pass List of object into preparedStatement, or for a better alternative

Tags: java, sql

I have a question about JDBC.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
      dbConnection.prepareStatement(
             "SELECT userid, roleid, name from permission 
              where (userid, roleid) in (?)");

// assume I cannot update the above line, which is maintained by others

// now I just get a PreparedStatement and a list of object
Set<Pair<Integer, Integer>> idPair = ....
```

How can I execute the query with `idPair` variable?

PS:  (`userid`, `roleid`) together are primary key for `permission` table

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not.

You need to resort to plain SQL with iteration and filtering.

This is not JDBC specific, but AFAIK universal to most drivers.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Victor, you mean I'd have SQL string first with `idPair`, then generate the PS with it? Yes, I couldn't find any other way to solve this. ( my team prefer have PS first, then bind the value. )

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you have to resort to that.